# Setting Custom Bindings in a Template, as part of a Custom Binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, custom-binding

The subject is a little confusing, but here is what I'm trying to do:

I have created a KnockoutJS custom binding to display a grid on my page.  This works well, I followed the SimpleGrid model on the site.  However, some of my fields are dates, booleans, etc.  I would like to use a custom binding to transform a date using the time ago plugin, etc.  Before I built the grid I would simply assign the custom binding in the grid.  Now that I am using a "reusable" grid binding I want to be able to pass in (as part of my column definitions) a list of bindings and values to assign in the template for the header and cells of my grid.

Here's the HTML in my page:

```
<div data-bind="grid: grid" />
```

Here's the HTML Page View Model:

```
 var tenantsViewModel = {
    navigateDetails: function (tenant) {
        document.location = '/Tenants/Details/' + tenant.TenantId;
    },
    navigateDomain: function (tenant) {
        window.open("http://" + tenant.Domain);
    },
    grid: new my.grid({
        resource: "system/tenants",
        columns: [
          { display: "Tenant", value: "Name", isLink: true },
          { display: "Enabled", value: "IsEnabled", isLink: false },
          { display: "Tenant Since", value: "CreatedOn", isLink: false },
          { display: "Domain", value: "Domain", isLink: true }
      ]
    })
};
tenantsViewModel.grid.update();
ko.applyBindings(tenantsViewModel);
```

Here's my custom grid binding and template:

```
// Object
my.grid = function (config) {
    var self = this;
    self.data = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.columns = config.columns;
    var resource = config.resource;

    my.grid.prototype.update = function () {
        // A Wrapper for $.ajax()/JSONP
        my.get(resource, function (data) {
            self.data(data);
        });
    };
};

// Templates
var templateEngine = new ko.nativeTemplateEngine();

templateEngine.addTemplate = function (templateName, templateMarkup) {
    document.write("<script type=\"text/html\" id='" + templateName + "'>" + templateMarkup + "<" + "/script>");
};

templateEngine.addTemplate("merlin_grid", "\
                <table class=\"data\">\
                    <thead>\
                        <tr data-bind=\"foreach: columns\">\
                           <th data-bind=\"text: display\"></th>\
                        </tr>\
                    </thead>\
                    <tbody data-bind=\"foreach: data\">\
                       <tr data-bind=\"foreach: $parent.columns\">\
                           <td data-bind=\"css: { link: isLink },text: typeof value == 'function' ? value($parent) : $parent[value] \"></td>\
                        </tr>\
                    </tbody>\
                </table>");

// Grid: Convert element into a full blown grid component
ko.bindingHandlers.grid = {
    init: function () {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    update: function (element, viewModelAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var viewModel = viewModelAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        while (element.firstChild)
            ko.removeNode(element.firstChild);

        var gridTemplateName = allBindings.gridTemplate || "merlin_grid";

        var gridContainer = element.appendChild(document.createElement("DIV"));
        ko.renderTemplate(gridTemplateName, viewModel, { templateEngine: templateEngine }, gridContainer, "replaceNode");
    }
};
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle so we can see the full context, including you custom binding? That will definitely help clarify your question

Comment: I can't post the whole thing to JSFiddle, partially because there is an AJAX call I can't replicate off the dev system.  And I can't really post any more code for legal reasons.

Comment: @BrentPabst jsfiddle has an echo API to help you emulate ajax calls, and you can abstract your code enough that it doesn't match any code you can't legally post. If you are asking for help on a problem, you should be prepared to give detail on it.

Comment: @Tyrsius Thanks for the tip on the Echo function, I'll check that out.  However, I still will not be able to post the entire set of code to JSFiddle, NDAs are a pain!  The grid itself works great, just not sure how I would go about passing in custom bindings for certain columns.  I'll see if I'm allowed to post the actual View Model that gets called, if so I'll post it in a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get this to work.  I've got a question out to the KnockoutJS user group as well.  If they ever respond I'll post the result here.